# Is $y(t) = \cos(t) + x(t)$ a time-invariant system?

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems

Is $y(t) = \cos(t) + x(t)$ a time-invariant system?

---

$y(t-k) = \cos(t-k) + x(t-k)$

But it isn't equal to $\cos(t) + x(t-k)$

So, would it be time-invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've answered the question yourself already. So, does the response to a shifted input equal the shifted response to the original (non-shifted) input? If so, then the system is time-invariant. Otherwise, it's a *time-varying* system.

Comment: It's a time-varying system then.

Comment: @SiddharthGarg: That's right.